# Mojolicious over HTTPS

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using Mojolicious for a web app that requires an encrypted connection, but I don't know how to add SSL support to Mojolicious.

My coworker sent me these: files domain.key, domain-bundle.crt, domain.crt

and my Mojolicious startup looks like this:

```
sub startup {
my $self = shift;
$self->secrets(['secretphrase']);
$self->config(hypnotoad => {listen => ['http://*:80']});
```

How can I add HTTPS support without having to use a reverse-proxy

Comment: You have to configure your web server (Apache, IIS etc) to perform the SSL encryption. Mojolicious is a web framework, not a web server.

Comment: @stevieb the question suggests that the app is using Hypnotoad which is indeed a web server and can support TLS - [this page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Daemon#listen) has some config details. While you can put Apache or Nginx in front of hypnotoad, that might not work well if websockets were being used.

Answer (score 13):

Found how to do it:

```
sub startup {
my $self = shift;
$self->secrets(['secretphrase']);
$self->config(hypnotoad => {
      listen => ['https://*:443?cert=/etc/tls/domain.crt&key=/etc/tls/domain.key']
  });
```

Comment: I ended up doing it with an nginx reverse proxy in front.

Answer (score -1):

```
sub startup {
my $self = shift;
$self->secrets(['secretphrase']);
$self->config(hypnotoad => {
        listen => ['https://*:443?cert=/path/to/domain.crt&key=/path/to/domain.key&ca=/path/to/domain-bundle.crt']
    });
```

Replace /path/to/domain-bundle.crt with the actual path to your domain-bundle.crt file

You need to run your mojo app with enough privileges to bind to ports below 1024, or you can use a reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache in front of your mojo app.