# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS on Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am running a Mojolicious app on Hypnotoad. It is listening to port 443 and it can be accessed through https.

how can I forward all HTTP request to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169375/mojolicious-over-https) your server listen only 443 port. So you should add another application to handle 80 port.

The best way to add nginx or apache in front of hypnotoad and do it there (redirect, rewrite).

But if you don't want to have nginx, you may write Mojolicious application
which listen [two ports](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Daemon#listen) and have hook [before_dispatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing.pod#Hooks) wich handle all requests and make redirect changing only scheme.

If you want i may to attempt to write such minimal example.

Upd. I decide to add [example](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/5776c0cf2d18992235cf)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not directly. While you could use iptables or similar to forward port 80 to 443, in practice that wouldn't work because the browser doesn't expect to have to do an SSL handshake for a plain HTTP URI. You have to run a trivial web app on port 80 (probably with a separate Hypnotoad or similar) that answers every request with a redirect to HTTPS -- probably either to some login page or to the same URI as requested with just the scheme changed.